# boost::asio how spawn multiple coroutine, and then join them?

Tags: c++, join, yield, coroutine, asio

i'm using boost::asio, my code like this:

```
void my_coroutine(boost::asio::io_context& io, boost::asio::yield_context yield)
{
        boost::asio::spawn(io, other_1_coroutine);
        boost::asio::spawn(io, other_2_coroutine);
        async_wait(other_1 and other_2);
        continue_do_something();
}
```

i want spawn 2 or more coroutine concurrently, and then async await them all.
i tried coroutine TS, but g++ does not support yet.
how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `spawn` function you pass as first argument *execution context* (as instance of `io_context` class). Inside this object, strictly inside `io_context::run` method coroutine function is executed.

All you need to wait until coroutine is completed, is to call `run` on `io_context` - provided you didn't use this `io` object to initiate some other asynchronous tasks (so you should create dedicated `io_context` instances for your coroutines).

If you want to handle multiple coroutines, you have to call in background threads `run` metod.

```
boost::asio::spawn(io, other_1_coroutine);
boost::asio::spawn(io, other_2_coroutine);

// join section:
std::thread th( [&](){ io.run(); } );
io.run();
th.join();

continue_do_something();
```

in the code above, we create one thread with calling `run`. So two invocations of `run` work concurrently and performing both started coroutines.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11016bd03985309f) (it is not 1:1 with your code, but it presents how you can join coroutines).

Comment: i'd like run all part of my program in async, no block, no thread-sleep/thread-join. is "composed asynchronous operation"/asio::async_initiate() the right way?

Comment: I dont get it. In title you are writing about "join", in question you said "and then async await them all". After starting coroutines by `spawn` and putting `run` in background threads, you can execute other code in parallel way, it is not what you want?

Comment: sorry for "join" word, i want async await all coroutine that spawn-ed, it should be "like join", also like python3: asyncio.wait(aws, *, loop=None, timeout=None, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)

Comment: If I got you right, you want to know something like JavaScript's promiseAll, which dispatches/starts the coroutines and de-blocks/advances/returns when it has successfully gathered/awaited ALL their results. Correct?